# How can I trigger effect on sibling component in vue3 in an idiomatic way?

Tags: vue.js, architecture, vuejs3

I have 2 components `Sibling1` and `Sibling2` that are placed side by side. I want to press a button on `Sibling1` and trigger an effect on `Sibling2`.

- This logic lives only inside the parent component, so no need to make it global
- It's not easy to take out this effect outside of the component and put it for instance on the parent

One way I thought of doing it is like this:

```js
// App.vue (parent)
const trigger = ref(null)
function setTrigger() {
  trigger.value = Symbol('new trigger')
}
</script>

<template>
    <SiblingOne @on-click="setTrigger" />
    <SiblingTwo :trigger="trigger" />
</template>



// Sibling1.vue
<script setup>
const emit = defineEmits(['on-click'])
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="emit('on-click')">update</button>
</template>

// Sibling2.vue
<script setup>
import { watch } from 'vue'
const props = defineProps({ trigger: null })

watch(
  () => props.trigger,
  () => console.log(new Date())
)
</script>
<template>Nothing to see here, check console</template>
```

I've seen the pattern above some times but maybe there are better alternatives. What would be a good way of doing this in vue3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The necessity for trigger variable suggests this is the case for a callback. `Sibling2` is supposed to expose it, `Sibling1` is supposed to call it:

*App.vue*

```
<script setup>
const siblingTwo = ref(null);
</script>

<template>
    <SiblingOne @click="siblingTwo?.trigger" />
    <!-- or -->
    <SiblingOne @click="siblingTwo.trigger()" />

    <SiblingTwo ref="siblingTwo" />
</template>
```

*Sibling2.vue*

```
<script setup>
import { defineExpose } from 'vue'

defineExpose({
  trigger() {
    console.log(new Date())
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: I suppose this is better. Maybe it's my habit of changing something based on passing data that makes it seem strange to expose in the other direction.

Comment: There may be cases for the way you did it but these were mostly workarounds IME

Comment: I used it mainly in React code. Indeed there doesn't seem to be any extra dependencies and there are less "moving" parts. 

In the case of React, the ref is not forwarded automatically (for historical reasons related to classes it seems) so it seems a bit simpler to me to use datas as trigger in those scenarios

Answer (score 1):

I hope it's okay that I recommend a package to use.

I use [tiny-emitter](https://github.com/scottcorgan/tiny-emitter) for this purpose. It's [lightweight](https://bundlephobia.com/package/tiny-emitter@2.1.0) and does exactly what you need it to do.

Just remember to turn the emit listener off as well.

Comment: This seems like a good option. It still is global but can be limited and it adds an extra dependency but it's so small it could probably just copy pasted. This should be almost the same as the `mitt` package right?

Comment: It is indeed like `mitt` (which I've only learned about now)
`mitt` looks better actually :smile:

If you're using `VUEX` or `PENIA` you could update a value and listen to changes in there too.